# What makes the Enum class uninheritable?

Tags: java, inheritance

I've been looking at [the source code of the `Enum` class](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Enum.java.html). It seems like a plain abstract class with a protected constructor to me. It's not final, it doesn't have any special annotations inside it and it doesn't use native code. And yet, it cannot be subclassed directly. In fact, the following code doesn't compile:

```
class Foo<E extends Enum<E>> extends Enum<E> {
    Foo(String name, int ordinal) {
        super(name, ordinal);
    }
}
```

I know that `Enum` is a special class in Java and I understand that there are good reasons why direct subclassing should be forbidden. But technically, how do you enforce this behavior?
Can a programmer create a similar non-final class that wouldn't allow direct subclassing despite having an accessible constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's only invalid to extend `Enum` directly *within the language*. Any time you declare an `enum`, that *does* create a subclass of `Enum`.

The way the JLS prevents you from "manually" declaring a class which extends `Enum` is simply to prohibit it explicitly. From [JLS section 8.1.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4):

> It is a compile-time error if the ClassType names the class Enum or any invocation of it.

(Where `ClassType` is the type you're extending.)

Without that rule, your code would have been perfectly valid.